# Jmeter Cache Manager - null exception

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load-testing

I have created a web test for simulating a browser behavior that I will use for load test.

Version: Jmeter 2.12

My Test plan

```
HTTP Request Defaults
Ultimate Thread Group 
-HTTP Cache Manager     
-HTTP Cookie Manager    
-Once Only Controller    
Login function    
-Random Controller   
 Random Http requests    
 Response Assertions
```

If I have `Use cache control/Expires header when processing GET requests`  unchecked there are no problems.

When I tick "Use cache control..." I get a lot of errors?

```
Sampler request:
Thread Name: jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group 1-5
Sample Start: 1970-01-01 01:00:00 CET
Load time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 418
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 418
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.lang.NullPointerException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: null

Response headers:
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
Request 
Null
```

Is this the normal behavior? Are thh pages not requested since they are in cache? Should I then remove my assertions? (I use response assertion, contain text) What assertion could I use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in 2.12, that was fixed in 2.13. See: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57579

If you want to still use, 2.12, as a workaround you can add this line to your jmeter.properties file

```
cache_manager.cached_resource_mode=RETURN_200_CACHE
```